# How to determine if the subset $K=\{ g\in S_4|2^g=2\}$ is a subgroup of $S_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm not sure exactly how to start.

I know that the group $S_4$ is a finite set of 4 symbols whose elements are all the permutations of the 4 symbols which sums up to 24 permutations.

That is, $S_4$ is defined as following :

$S_4 = \{id = \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\1&2&3&4\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\4&3&2&1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\1&3&2&4\end{pmatrix}... \}$

How exactly is the following subset is defined 
$K=\{ g\in S_4|2^g=2\} ?$

What exactly $2^g$ means in the context of the group $S_4$?

Comment: As noted in the answer below, you need to determine whether the set of permutations fixing $2$ is a subgroup of $S_{4}$.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Oh, I think I understand. The subset $K$ contains all the permutations where the element 2 is fixed, that is always mapped to itself. So for example I can't have the following element in the set $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\4&3&2&1\end{pmatrix}$ because 2 isn't fixed. correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined $S_4$ as the group of permtuations of a specific 4-element set: $\{1,2,3,4\}$.  The "$2$" in $2^g$ should be thought of as an element of that set, and $2^g$ is simply the image of the element $2$ under the permutation $g$.  So the question is asking about the permutations which map the element $2$ to itself.

Comment: Can you please show me some examples of elements in the subset $K$ ?

Comment: The identity element of course or $\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\4&2&1&3\end{pmatrix}$. And $K$ is actually a subgroup $S_4$, which is more than a set without an algebraic structure. Maybe you can show now that $K \cong S_3$.